# How to have OFFSET/FETCH and WITH TIES together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

`OFFSET FETCH` does not support a logical equivalent to `TOP (n) WITH TIES` option, which ensures determinism by returning all ties.

Is there any workaround to have `OFFSET FETCH` and `WITH TIES` together?

**Create statement with sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(Id INT, Name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT #tbl
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'c'
```

---

**TOP**

`SELECT TOP 3 * FROM #tbl ORDER BY Id`

```
Id  Name
1   a
1   a
2   b
```

---

**TOP n WITH TIES**

`SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES * FROM #tbl ORDER BY Id`

```
Id  Name
1   a
1   a
2   b
2   b
2   b
```

---

**OFFSET FETCH**

```
SELECT *
FROM #tbl
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY

Id  Name
1   a
1   a
2   b
```

Probably we need to use Ranking function to achieve this??

Comment: "Probably we need to use Ranking function to achieve this??" I guess you answered your own question. I guess you'll have to use both `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` over there. Find what's the `DENSE_RANK` value for `n'th` `ROW_NUMBER` and pick rows up to these.

Comment: "... ensures determinism by returning all ties" - of course, the other way to ensure determinism is to avoid ties - find enough columns/expressions such that `ORDER BY` is always sufficient to uniquely order the rows of the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use them together without FETCH statement inside the CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT Id, Name
  FROM #tbl
  ORDER BY Id
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  )
  SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES *
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY Id
```

See [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1239)

Example with offset 3 [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1241)

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT Id, Name
  FROM #tbl
  ORDER BY Id
  OFFSET 3 ROWS
  )
  SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES *
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how do you do it when you want to offset 3 rows and fetch next 3 rows but with ties. In your answer there is no need for the table expression and you can remove it and use TOP 3 on your main query.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain. If you want to offset 3 rows just use OFFSET 3 ROWS clause, if you need fetch 3 rows with ties just use SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES * clause. I've put example for you.

Comment: The question is: OFFSET n(3) ROWS and then FETCH NEXT n(3) ROWS but with ties.

Comment: i've created new example for you.

Comment: Thanks. Good and easy solution. Hope it helps someone else. The point is there is no need to fetch after offsetting few rows.

Comment: You're welcome, and you're absolutely right that point was that no need to fetch after offsetting few rows;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM #tbl
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: So far, SQL Server only supports `ROWS ONLY` from the standard SQL syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind! @RanMarciano